# How can I modify steps/tags with a specflow generator plugin?

Tags: c#, .net, tags, specflow, gherkin

I am trying to write a generator plugin for specflow to modify the steps or tags that end up in the generated `feature.cs` files.

I have tried to follow the method described here:

[SpecFlow- is it possible to programmatically add lines to a scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610533/specflow-is-it-possible-to-programmatically-add-lines-to-a-scenario?newreg=c2d417da44a041d4bf51f4fa4c4502d6)

relevant code:

```
  public new CodeNamespace GenerateUnitTestFixture(Feature feature, string testClassName, string targetNamespace)
  {
      foreach (var scenario in feature.Scenarios)
      {
          scenario.Steps.Insert(0, new Given { Text = "Given I have <Theme> set as my current theme" });

          //add any other steps you need....
      }

      return base.GenerateUnitTestFixture(feature, testClassName, targetNamespace);
  }
```

The definition of **GenerateUnitTestFixture** has since changed in UnitTestFeatureGenerator, but using roughly the same method I am unable to insert steps as the entire **GherkinDocument** argument passed in to the function is readonly including steps so they cannot be modified or added to.

```
public new CodeNamespace GenerateUnitTestFixture(SpecFlowDocument document, string testClassName, string targetNamespace)
{
      var feature = document.Feature;

      foreach (ScenarioDefinition scenarioDefinition in feature.Children)
      {
          scenarioDefinition.Steps.///Cannot insert
      }

      return base.GenerateUnitTestFixture(document, testClassName, targetNamespace);

}
```

The same problem occurs for tags. I cant find much up-to-date documentation on this stuff, is it still possible to modify steps/tags or is it no longer supported?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you add additional steps to a scenario in the background, you are hiding something from someone who only reads the feature file and does not know about this generation.

Comment: Well ideally I want to attach a uniquely identifying tag to each test so that individual failing tests can be re-run later.